# SAS - Keep only columns listed in a separate dataset

Tags: sas

I have two datasets. The first, `big_dataset`, has around 3000 columns, most of which are never used. The second, `column_list`, contains a single column called `column_name` with around 100 values. Each value is the name of a column I want to keep.

I want to filter `big_dataset` so that only columns in `column_list` are kept, and the rest are discarded.

If I were using Pandas dataframes in Python, this would be a trivial task:

```python
cols = column_list['column_name'].tolist()
smaller_dataset = big_dataset[cols]
```

However, I can't figure out the SAS equivalent. `Proc Transpose` doesn't let me turn the rows into headers. I can't figure out a statement in the data step that would let this work, and as far as I'm aware this isn't something that `Proc SQL` could handle. I've read through the docs on `Proc Datasets` and that doesn't seem to have what I need either.

Comment: You need to reference the variable names with CODE.  So you have a code generation problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain a list of columns from `column_list` to use against `big_dataset`, you can query the `column_list` table and put the result into a macro variable. This can be achieved with `PROC SQL` and the `SEPARATED BY` clause:

```
proc sql noprint;
  select column_name
  into :cols separated by ','
  from column_list;
  create table SMALLER_DATASET AS
  select &cols.
  from WORK.BIG_DATASET;
quit;
```

Alternatively you may use `SEPARATED BY ' '` and then use the resulting list in a `KEEP` statement or dataset option:

```
proc sql noprint;
  select column_name
  into :cols separated by ' '
  from column_list;
quit;

data small_dataset;
  set big_dataset (keep=&cols.);
  /* or keep=&cols.; */
run;
```